# XQuery XmlSpy delete

Tags: xml, xquery, altova, xmlspy

I'm attempting to delete an XML node through XQuery using the in-build XQuery compiler in Altova XMLSpy.

```
xquery version "1.0" encoding "UTF-8";
for $customer in doc("Customers.xml")/dataroot/Customers
where $customer/CustomerID = "ALFKI"
return delete node $customer;
```

The issue is the compiler doesn't see 'delete node' as valid syntax, whereas it's defined here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/

It complains with an error "Unexpected token node $customer".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the missplaced semicolon after `$customer`.

```
xquery version "1.0" encoding "UTF-8";
for $customer in doc("Customers.xml")/dataroot/Customers
where $customer/CustomerID = "ALFKI"
return delete node $customer (: here was the semicolon :)
```

Otherwise, your XQuery is valid.

Answer (score 2):

the fact is that XMLSpy don't support XQuery Update Facility, hence the delete keyword is not valid